# Tomcat file permissions

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, user-permissions

I have existing version of `tomcat7` which installed with default apt-get.
which is by default running on its own user "`tomcat7`" On ubuntu 16.

Now I want `tomcat9` as well running on same server with different port. I have downloaded tomcat9 manually and extracted in /opt/tomcat9.

It is running fine. But the problem is I am running `tomcat9` with "`sh /opt/tomcat9/startup.sh`" command. which is executing it with `root` user. And the files which are uploaded earlier are in directory "`/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/images`".

And the application which running on `tomcat9` is accessing same files and also writing files in same directory. But `tomcat7` is not able to access those files since those are created with "`root`" user.
How can I run tomcat9 with same user which tomcat7 uses i.e. 'tomcat7'

Comment: Set up a docker container, duplicate the files from tomcat7 to docker container tomcat9. Now you avoid all the janky hacky two different user accounts.

Comment: Or you could create a common group between 7 and 9, then modify the file perms to allow group access.